# My CPU is reaching 160% on Google Cloud and I can't seem to figure out why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, cpu, nonblocking

So I was working on this project and I've deployed it to the virtual machine on google cloud with a machine type of g1-small (v1 CPU, 1.7 GB). In the monitoring section, the CPU reaches upwards of 175% with 160% being the average. Google recommends me to increase my machine type to a custom (v1 CPU, 1.75 GB), but I'm not quite sure what's eating up the CPU.

I have read into blocking and non-blocking in node.js and I know that my code is currently non-blocking so that may be an issue. But if I change it to blocking, the code will run sequentially and it will run slower.

Thank you in advance.

Here's my code: https://github.com/QuaziH/CUNYfirst-API/blob/master/looper.js

```
const db = require('./db/index');
const text = require('./text');
const api = require('./cf-api');

let looper = () => {
    db.query(`SELECT DISTINCT institution, term, subject FROM classes`, async (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.error('Error fetching client', error);
        }

        if(response.rowCount === 0){
            console.log(`Table is empty`);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
                let allClasses = await api.getAllSections(`${response.rows[i].institution}`, `${response.rows[i].term}`, `${response.rows[i].subject}`);
                db.query(`SELECT phone, carrier, topic, class_num FROM classes WHERE institution='${response.rows[i].institution}' AND term='${response.rows[i].term}' AND subject='${response.rows[i].subject}'`, (error, response) => {
                    if (error) {
                        return console.error('Error fetching client', error);
                    }

                    for (let j = 0; j < response.rows.length; j++) {
                        let status;
                        try {
                            status = allClasses[response.rows[j].class_num].Status;
                        } catch (e) {
                            if (response.rows[j].carrier === '@tmomail.net' || response.rows[j].carrier === '@mymetropcs.com') {
                                text.emailError(`${response.rows[j].phone}${response.rows[j].carrier}`, `Your class ${response.rows[j].topic}- ${response.rows[j].class_num} does not exist in CUNYfirst anymore`);
                            } else {
                                text.twilio(`${response.rows[j].phone}`, `Uh oh! \n Your class ${response.rows[j].topic}- ${response.rows[j].class_num} does not exist in CUNYfirst anymore`);
                            }
                            db.query(`DELETE FROM classes WHERE phone='${response.rows[j].phone}' AND class_num=${response.rows[j].class_num}`, (err, res) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(`Error deleting from database: ${err}`);
                                }
                            });
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (status === 'Closed') {
                            console.log(`Class is still closed ${response.rows[j].topic}- ${response.rows[j].class_num}`);
                        } else if (status === 'Open') {
                            if (response.rows[j].carrier === '@tmomail.net' || response.rows[j].carrier === '@mymetropcs.com') {
                                text.emailOpen(`${response.rows[j].phone}${response.rows[j].carrier}`, `Your class ${response.rows[j].topic}- ${response.rows[j].class_num} is now open!`);
                            } else {
                                text.twilio(`${response.rows[j].phone}`, `Class Opened! \n Your class ${response.rows[j].topic}- ${response.rows[j].class_num} is now open!`);
                            }
                            db.query(`DELETE FROM classes WHERE phone='${response.rows[j].phone}' AND class_num=${response.rows[j].class_num}`, (err, res) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(`Error deleting from database: ${err}`);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};

setInterval(looper, 300000);
```

Comment: How does it run on your local machine?

Comment: @GaryHayes sorry I misread your comment and thought you meant virtual. On my local machine it works fine, but idk how to test it using google's custom instance machine type.

Answer (score 0):

Well that explains because Google Cloud Platform uses virtual machines. Virtual machines want to perform like a bare metal machine. My next step would be to analyze your Cpu performance. You can do it from opening two SSH windows (one launching the code, other monitoring) or by connecting from your remote. From the Google Cloud you have tools like the [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) monitoring (which would be more than suitable for this testing) and the [Stackdriver login](https://cloud.google.com/logging/). Also you have the serial port output from your instance. With this information you can make the changes to adapt this instance to yoru code.

Comment: So after a bit of playing around with WebStorm's flame graph I found out cheerio was the cause of the increase in CPU. I still haven't spent time looking into it more but I did manage to lower it from 16% to 11%, however I don't know if this is a memory leak or what. I don't know much about memory either to be honest, so if you know a link or resource that can help, can you link it please? Thank you!

Comment: Hi quazi, I can't help you I'm not an expert with javascript and memory. Sorry.